# Is it possible to run a Firmware Over The Air update server?

Tags: device-firmware, ota-update

Is it possible to run a Firmware Over The Air update server?

and is it possible to configure stock devices to point at it?

Comment: I think you're going to need to tell us a little more about what you're trying to do here. OTA servers are possible, Google, some manufacturers, and some phone networks all run their own, I believe there's even some custom ROMs (CM?) that can do OTA now. Nothing particularly complicated about the server end (an HTTP interface that can version check and serve large binaries is pretty much all it actually does), there is no built-in way to get a device to check _and trust_ a 3rd party server for updates, this would need to be baked in to the ROM. Then there's actually updating the device...

Comment: that's unfortunate.  my s60's have let me configure update servers, so i was hoping to be able to do the same with android.

Comment: Did you find another way?

Comment: I ended up switching to CM and using CyanDelta.  (This was before CM Updater was revived.)

Comment: Related: [Setting up a Android OTA server for ROM distribution](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/49341/)

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to run your own OTA Server. You can use the infrastructure from https://www.otaupdatecenter.pro

Comment: that looks like what i'll end up with.  do i have to flash with a custom rom first?  is there no way to install a custom rom over the air from a stock rom?